# Voltage across battery which is being charged

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries, electronics

When I connect my 7 V battery (having 7 V voltage ) to a 10 V power supply then across the battery it shows the voltage being the same as the instantaneous voltage of the battery.

Now if I connect the same battery with 17 V then the voltage across the battery shows nearly 10 V (means input voltage - instantaneous battery voltage).

Why is the voltage in the 1st case showing the same as the battery and in the 2nd case the voltage of the battery is less than the input?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! I have slightly edited your question to (hopefully) improve clarity. If I misunderstood your intention, please feel free to further [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: What do you call "instantaneous battery voltage"? Don't you have a DC voltage?

Answer (score 1):

When two batteries are connected in parallel the voltage between the terminals of the batteries will depend on the internal resistance of each battery. So model each battery as an ideal voltage source in series with a resistor equal to its internal resistance and apply Kirchhoff’s voltage law to determine the voltage between the terminals.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion but i want some more practical tips. I have used a power supply (not battery) then in that case what woulg be the terminal Mam voice is not clear of battery

Comment: Doesn’t matter if it’s a battery or any generic voltage source. There’s a source impedance associated with all real voltage sources and my answer still applies.